# Haskell records, cleaner approach?

Tags: haskell, record

I've read about some of the issues with Haskell records, in particular, the fact that two elements in the same module can not have the same name.

I understand you can work around this by having separate modules, but I didn't want to do that and instead tried this approach:

```
class HasX a where
  x :: a -> X

data D1 = D1 { d1_x :: X, ... }
instance HasX D1 where
  x = d1_x

data D2 = D2 { d2_x :: X, ... }
instance HasX D2 where
  x = d2_x
```

(This only does gets, not sets, I'd of course need to write more code to do sets).

However, it seems the class and instance declarations for all this seem like a like of boilerplate which should be able to be eliminated, using template haskell or something else.

Is there a library or extension to GHC that makes such an approach less messy to write?

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that since the two fields might not have the same type.

Comment: For my purposes, assume fields with the same name have the same type. I won't have fields with the same name having different types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems [Data.Has](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/has/0.5.0.1/doc/html/Data-Has.html) encapsulates a lot of what you're looking for. In their vocabulary they  I think that their `Knows` type-class is closer to your `Has`, and it also provides a signature for injection as well.

They also use a labeling mechanism to treat an issue that I don't think you've considered yet: records which contain fields that have the same type. They use type-level labels to do this disambiguation.

For convenience, there also seems to be some support that provides a generator for the `Has` instance with template Haskell in [Has-TH](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/has-th)

You can find more type-level labels and other record-relevant material in works of the Oleg the Type Magician, like [OOHaskell](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~ralf/OOHaskell/) (also with Ralf Lämmel).

Comment: Could you point me to some tutorial style documentation for `Data.Has` (and `Has-TH` for that matter). It looks roughly like what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure how to put it all together.

Comment: Actually, I found this for `Data.Has`: https://github.com/nonowarn/has/blob/master/examples/Announce04.lhs

Answer (score 0):

data-accessor-template may at least help to write the set/get accessors. Maybe some people can come up with the Template Haskell code for generation of classes and instances for every record field name.
However, I do not use the Template Haskell stuff myself. It restricts you to GHC, and even to specific GHC versions, since Template Haskell changes between different GHC versions. Having one (major) record per module really pays off.